# Sharepoint Foundation Workflow + ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, reporting-services, workflow

I have a requirement from HR to make a process managed online. There is a workflow involved, I was checking my options and found out that we can make custom workflow on Sharepoint Foundation and deploy it for use. I would like to use the ASP.net for user interface and Sharepoint for workflow and data storage.

Is this possible at all or Sharepoint Foundation not adequate?

Can I create reports on SSRS from the data stored in Sharepoint lists?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Workflow Manager 1.0 for the creation of your  Workflow without even using SharePoint.